# Unbind click when class name is counted 6 times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to count how many times the class name `imgSelected` is used in my current document using a variable called `answers`. I'm doing this so that the users won't be able to click on any more items after the 6 item cap.

However, what's happening is that `answers` is incremented every time an `#item` is clicked, regardless of whether it has the class name `imgSelected`. Also, `answers` doesn't decrement when the div is clicked again. I need the variable `answers` to increment and decrement depending on how many times `imgSelected` appears on the document, and I need to unbind the click event when imgSelected has appeared 6 times.

**What I have so far**

```
$("#item1, #item2, #item3, #item4, #item5, #item6, #item7, #item8, #item9, #item10").click(function() {
    answers++
    console.log(answers);
    $(this).toggleClass("imgSelected");
});
```

Please help? I'm so stumped.

Comment: can you make [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use benefits of live node lists:

```
var answers = document.getElementsByClassName("imgSelected");

$("#item1, #item2, #item3, #item4, #item5, #item6, #item7, #item8, #item9, 
#item10").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("imgSelected");
    console.log(answers.length);
});
```

Now whenever you add or remove class `imgSelected` `answers.length` will always reflect actual number of selected items.

Another recommendation, instead of dosen of ids give items the same class and use something like:

```
$('.item').click(function() { ... });
```

The only disadvantage: IE9+.

If you need old IE support you can simply reselect selected items and check its length with jQuery:

```
var answers = $('.imgSelected').length;
```

in fact it's still going to be pretty fast (in modern browsers and fast enough).

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be  **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c3v9a/3/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="item1">Hello item 1</div>
<div id="item2">Hello item 2</div>
<div id="item3">Hello item 3</div>
<div id="item4">Hello item 4</div>
<div id="item5">Hello item 5</div>
<div id="item6">Hello item 6</div>
<div id="item7">Hello item 7</div>
<div id="item8">Hello item 8</div>
<div id="item9">Hello item 9</div>
<div id="item10">Hello item 10</div>
```

**jQUERY**

```
var answers = 0;


$("#item1, #item2, #item3, #item4, #item5, #item6, #item7, #item8, #item9, #item10").click(function () {

    $(this).toggleClass("imgSelected");

    if ($(this).hasClass('imgSelected')) {
        if (answers < 6) {
            answers++
        }
    } else {
        answers--
    }
    console.log(answers);

});
```